# Update list on page without resetting state in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I have a `Host.js` file which has a track list which is updated as defined by the setTrackListener() function. My issue is that everytime the function is called, the trackList isn't actually updated. Here is an example print out:

```
Change detected in setTrackListener
 LOG  Track Name: TEST
 LOG  Current trackList:
 LOG  NewArray: TEST
 LOG  trackList after set:
```

Here is my code:

```
let authToken = "";
let roomID = "";

export default function Host({ navigation }) {
  if (roomID == "") {
    roomID = createRoom();
  }
  const [trackList, setTrackList] = useState([]);

  if (authToken == "") {
    getAuthAccessToken().then((t) => (authToken = t));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTrackListener(roomID, (t) => {
      if (t != null) {
        console.log("Track Name: " + t.name);
        console.log("Current trackList: " + trackList);
        const newArray = [...trackList];
        newArray.push(t.name);
        console.log("NewArray: " + newArray);
        setTrackList(newArray);
        console.log("trackList after set: " + trackList);
      }
    });
 
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Hosting {roomID}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={trackList}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item}</Text>}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    color: "#590",
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});
```

`setTrackListener` is defined in a seperate file, where I listen to changes on a specific Google Firebase Database. Here is that code:

```
let setTrackListener = (id, onChange) => {
  let tracksRef = ref(database, `rooms/${id}/tracks`);
  onChildAdded(tracksRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log("Change detected in setTrackListener");
    onChange(data);
  });
};
```

If I instead update the trackList with button like the following, it does update:

```
<Button
  title={"Test"}
  onPress={() => {
  const newArray = [...trackList, "TEST"];
  setTrackList(newArray);
  console.log(trackList);
}}
></Button>
```

Comment: you can use redux to store this list, in that way whenever list is updated UI will update too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**:
convert your `setTrackList(newArray);` inside the `useEffect` function to

```js
setTrackList((trackList) => [...trackList, t.name]);
```

---

I think your implementation on setTrackListener is correct.

So I think the main reason is that the `trackList` variable in `useEffect` is wrapped in a **stale closure**, this is a trait of Javascript that,
when you define a function, and it uses a variable outside of that function,
it will cache the value of that variable at the time the function is defined, and always return the same value (i.e. empty array in this case).

To fix that, you need to either put `trackList` variable into the dependency array of `useEffect`, or, pass a callback function to the setState function to avoid the need for access `trackList` inside `useEffect`.

Suggestion:
convert your `setTrackList(newArray);` in the useEffect function to

```js
setTrackList((trackList) => [...trackList, t.name]);
```

and do not use `console.log(trackList)` in the callback function (you won't see the value since it is always `[]`), either put the console log to the function body (quite dirty, only use for debugging), or print the value inside the `setTrackList`'s callback

```
setTrackList((trackList) => {
  const newArray = [...trackList, t.name]
  console.log(newArray)
  return newArray
});
```

If that doesn't work, another possible reason you didn't see the updated trackList in your output is **React does not update the state immediately**, the `setState` function will trigger a re-render, and the states are updated in a batch in the next re-render.

But in many cases, the update takes effects immediately, but you cannot rely on that.

---

P.S.
One thing to notice is that the `useEffect` does not unsubscribe to `onChildAdded` when the component is unmounted, this might cause some performance issues, so it will be better to re-write the `setTrackListener` and `useEffect` to

```js
// In the separate file, return the unsubscribe function from `onChildAdded`
const setTrackListener = (id, onChange) => {
  let tracksRef = ref(database, `rooms/${id}/tracks`);
  return onChildAdded(tracksRef, (snapshot) => {
    const data = snapshot.val();
    console.log("Change detected in setTrackListener");
    onChange(data);
  });
};

// In the useEffect hook, return the unsubscribe function which will get called during unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = setTrackListener(roomID, (t) => {
      if (t != null) {
        console.log("Track Name: " + t.name);
        console.log("Current trackList: " + trackList);
        const newArray = [...trackList];
        newArray.push(t.name);
        console.log("NewArray: " + newArray);
        setTrackList(newArray);
        console.log("trackList after set: " + trackList);
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe
  }, []);
```

References:

https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/#3-state-closure-in-useeffect

https://blog.logrocket.com/why-react-doesnt-update-state-immediately/

Comment: This was very helpful and seems to have fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianRusso Glad that works! :D This issue is really tricky tbh

Answer (score 1):

The reason explained by [Tyson-Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8581245/tyson-z) seems appropriate.

I would suggest the following changes.

Create a state variable to keep track of initialization state.

```
const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
```

Create a separate callback function

```
  const onChangeCallback = useCallback((t) => {
        if (t != null) {
            console.log("Track Name: " + t.name);
            console.log("Current trackList: " + trackList);
            const newArray = [...trackList];
            newArray.push(t.name);
            console.log("NewArray: " + newArray);
            setTrackList(newArray);
            console.log("trackList after set: " + trackList);
        }
    },[trackList]);
```

Change your useEffect hook with the following

```
  useEffect(() => {
        if (!initialized) {
            setListener(roomID, onChangeCallback);
            setInitialized(true);
        }
    }, [onChangeCallback,initialized]);
```

Test, if it's working

```
  // Only for testing
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(trackList);
        }, 1000)
    })
```

Hope it helps.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To observe the updated state value, you can make use of the useEffect hook with a dependency on the trackList state.

By adding [trackList] as the dependency array in the useEffect hook, the callback function will be called whenever the trackList state changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setTrackListener(roomID, (t) => {
    if (t != null) {
      console.log("Track Name: " + t.name);
      console.log("Current trackList: " + trackList);
      const newArray = [...trackList, t.name];
      console.log("NewArray: " + newArray);
      setTrackList(newArray);
    }
  });
}, [trackList]);
```

Comment: This seems to be creating an infinite loop, where adding one element to the trackList causes a chain reaction so that it keeps trying to add the item. the setTrackListener function sets a new listener everytime it is called, so I believe repeatedly calling it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect  with [] will only run once. You need to add the changing dependencies e.g. [t]. t, t.name, or any props that their changes should trigger the setTrackListener.

Also

```
console.log("trackList after set: " + trackList)
```

next to

```
setTrackList(newArray)
```

would not show the latest state of the trackList.

Try below as a seperate useEffect:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Current trackList: " + trackList);
  }, [trackList]);
```

Comment: I believe the setTrackListener function should only run once since it is merely initializing what the listener should be. I do not want to add multiple listeners to the same event.